# is there is a way to display HTML Table in UIlable

Tags: ios

I want to be able to render HTML Table Tag as a table in UILabel

I do not want to use UIWebview for performance issues

Comment: Did you checked if it works with `NSAttributedString` and HTML?

Comment: Thank you ,, yes it works with NSAttributedString

Comment: But i need something that work with IOS 6

Comment: Since `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is available since iOS7, you may have to look for some other code in GitHub or do the parsing yourself.

Comment: I have searched for libraries to do so ,, but they supports  tags other than table tag

Comment: Did you find any answer?